# Trouble with Template Route & Pagination

Tags: pagination, template-routes

I have created a template route for the typical blog scenario where I have an index template in a "blog" template group that lists blog posts along with a detail template that shows full blog posts.

I have my template route set up like so:
[image: Template Route]

It works fine except for the pagination on the index page. I get 404 errors with pagination.

I have tried adding /{pagination} & /{pagination:pagination} to the end of the route along with trying to add /blog/{pagination} & /blog/{pagination:pagination} as a route for the index template but nothing works.

Any help on getting pagination to work with this is much appreciated.

Using EE v3.5.6.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is add `{page:pagination}` to the end of the route.  So something like:

```
/blog/{story:alpha_dash}/{page:pagination}
```

HTH

Comment: I still get a 404 error.

Comment: There was a typo in the example route that I've corrected now - that pattern works just fine on my EE3.5.5 system, so if you are getting a 404 then something else is also going on...

Comment: I had it correct and it's still not working. I have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: Ok. So I just figured something out. I had dynamic="yes" because I'm also using categories to filter the blog list. With dynamic="yes" categories worked but pagination did not. Changing it to dynamic="no" fixed the pagination but now categories don't work. How do I get both of them to work together?

Comment: Probably you need to explicitly identify the category using a parameter within your `channel:entries` tag (or whatever you are using).  How you do this depends on how your EE system is configured - but a common way is to simply identify the category along the lines of... `category="x|y|z"` where x, y, z are the category ids you want to include.  Alternatively you can use one of the category manipulation plugins (like `Low seg2cat`  or `construct categories`) and get the ID from a slug or some-such.

Comment: Actually dynamic="no" was not the issue. I have categories working and pagination only works on URLs other than /blog/P2. For example, if I am filtering by a category, pagination works with a URL such as /blog/category/category-1/P2. But pagination does not work when there are no other segments in the URL other than segment_1 (blog). Still confused by what is going on here.

Comment: I think to get to bottom of problem you'll need to share a bit more of your EE setup: template routes are finicky things for sure, and without a picture of what else is going on I'm not sure what else can be suggested.  The pattern shared before can work (e.g. I have it working).  But I guess it depends what other routes you have defined, and what happens in the routed template.

Comment: I only have one other route created for a totally different template group. My channel entries tag on the main blog index template is as follows: `{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" orderby="date" sort="desc" dynamic="yes" status="open" disable="category_fields|member_data" paginate="bottom" limit="2"}` Let me know what other info you might need. Thanks.